# Sybase LOAD TABLE USING CLIENT FILE failed in java code, using jconn3.jar

Tags: java, jdbc, sap-iq

When using jconn3.jar to connect to Sybase IQ database, and execute 
**LOAD TABLE ...CLIENT FILE** statement in Statement.execute(...) method.

**Got error: SQL Anywhere Error -1006140: I/O Error on file c:/aa**

But in Sybase's Interactive SQL client, this command run correctly and table data can loaded from c:/aa file successfully.

What's the reason? how to fix this?

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally came to the solution: use the iAnywhere JDBC driver (but it is not a Type 4 "Pure Java" driver 
).

http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1037304

Comment: Whunmr, I ran into the same issue. After reading your post I switched over to the iAnywhere JDBC Driver. I am on Windows so I configured an ODBC Data Source for DBODBC11.dll. In my java project I am using jodbc.jar from SQL Anywhere 11. My connection string is pretty simple. "jdbc:ianywhere:DSN=dw". I can get a connection, but I now get the following error: [Sybase][ODBC Driver][Sybase IQ]Syntax error near 'LOAD'. Any Ideas? What exactly did you have to do in order to get this to work? Thanks!

Comment: Try not to use ODBC data source, Connect to SybaseIQ directly through the iAnywhere JDBC driver.